# Maven Profiles not working and failing tests

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm starting to use profiles with Maven in order to build multi-environment jars.

I followed the [official docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html) to do this.

**First, validation question:**

I have read that you should always have one package generated by **Maven** project, but I only want to generate multi-environment jars (i.e.: *only changing a properties file for each jar*). I don't consider necessary to generate multiple projects to do this, am I right?

**Now the explanation:**

I have an app that reads a file and applies a certain set of reviews before going to insert some of the information to the database. I want to test that this validations are ok, and that I get correct results whether or not it fails later at the database. **So in this app I use a dynamically set DAO**. This is: my app gets the DAO class from the **config.properties** file at runtime. I created some facade DAOs that will simulate the real DAO (for example: DAOApproveAll, that will simulate that all the transactions in the database went ok).

In the unit testing I load **config.properties** to change (and later revert the change) of the value of the param *daoimplclass* that is the one that holds the class. For example:

```
 Properties prop = Configurator.getProperties("config");
    final String DAODEFAULT = prop.getProperty("daoimplclass");
    final static String DAOAPPROVEALL = "com.package.dao.DAOAllApproved";
    public void testAllAproved() {
        try {
            Processor processor = Processor.getInstance();
            prop.setProperty("daoimplclass", DAOAPPROVEALL);
            ...
         }
         finally{prop.setProperty("daoimplclass", DAODEFAULT);}
```

I do many tests (using different DAO facades) in order to validate what would happen if different results occur in the database.

Now, I changed my **config.properties** to 2 files: **config-dev.properties** and **config-prod.properties**. And changed the original **pom.xml** to use profiles like this:

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>dev</id>
     <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>test</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>run</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <tasks>
                   <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>
                   <copy file="src/main/resources/config-dev.properties"
                         tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>
                 </tasks>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
             <skip>false</skip>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>jar</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <classifier>dev</classifier>
                 <source>1.6</source>
                 <target>1.6</target>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
   </profile>
    <profile>
     <id>prod</id>
     <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>test</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>run</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <tasks>
                   <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>
                   <copy file="src/main/resources/config-prod.properties"
                         tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>
                 </tasks>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
             <skip>true</skip>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>jar</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <classifier>prod</classifier>
                 <source>1.6</source>
                 <target>1.6</target>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
   </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Now when I do "Clean and build"  in Netbeans I get errors executing the tests because it can't find the **config.properties**. Of course I create a third **config.properties** (the other two will be with the -dev and -prod) ant it compiles but doesn't generate 2 jars but only one.

---

**My formal questions:**

- What am I doing wrong with the profiles?
- How can I allow that the tests run Ok and only for dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To active the profile via Netbeans, you may try the following task: -

1. Right click at your project and select `properties` from the context menu.
2. Select the `Configurations` from `Categories` on the left panel.
3. At the right panel you will see the various profiles defined in your pom. You can `Activate` them by selecting them and click `Activate` button or you can create the new on by clicking the `Add` button.

I hope this may help.