# Method to run maven command in Netbean

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-7

How can I run `mvn clean install -Pjnlp` command in Netbean 7.3 ?

Comment: you don't run these commands in netbeans. You run these commands in command prompt / shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[To activate the profile via Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276319/maven-profiles-not-working-and-failing-tests/15284901#15284901), you may try the following task: -

1. Right click at your project and select `properties` from the context menu.
2. Select the `Configurations` from `Categories` on the left panel.
3. At the right panel you will see the various profiles defined in your pom. You can `Activate` them by selecting them and click `Activate` button or you can create the new on by clicking the `Add` button.

To achieve your requirement as `mvn clean install -Pjnlp` is simply just `right click` at the project and select `Clean and Build`. The `Clean and Build` calls `mvn clean install` together with the activate profile.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Alternatively, the project's popup menu has the Custom > Goals... action where you can enter your goals and profiles and run the maven build. Additionally you can remember the setup and it will show up on the popup of the project in Custom> submenu..